# How to create a div that will stay on the right middle of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to interact with a telephony system using a web service.

When a user is on a phone call, I would like to create a div that has multiple button

1. Hang Up
2. Hold/Resume
3. Send To Voice Main
4. Transfer

But I need this div to stay on the right side of the screen and the middle. even when the user scrolls down I still want this div to be top most and on the right.

I will design the div but my question is how to make it stay on the right/middle of the screen at all time
How can I do this?

Comment: What have you done so far?
You need to show us some work to start with...

Comment: Seems you are familiar with how SO works, and you already asked 264 question, so you know you have to provide you tried code so far. see this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How did you get to 2.5k rep and still think its ok to ask a question like this?

Comment: @JK. I see this all the time and I always ask myself the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common question, find a great explanation [here](https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/)

```
div {
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      right: 0px;
      transform: translate(0, -50%);
    }
```

Comment: You should change to `transform: translate(0, -50%);`, otherwise the object will not be on the right edge any more

Comment: @BenPhilipp good spot! Answer changed

Comment: This is one reason why this site is flooded with garbage questions.  They still get answered anyway.  If you do not answer them, then they will go away.

Comment: @JK This is not a garbage question. It is a simple question, yes, but if you are a beginner it can be hard. Having a high reputation doesn't mean to be expert in every subject. The question is completely valid within the stackoverflow rules and was not marked as duplicate. So your downvotes did create a tit-for-tat situation (I didn't join this btw) which has been redone by the system.
But i learned one thing: I am not going to answer a question that isn't at least a day old.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/menus.en.html) site having exactly what you want? See the green section links.

```
<ul id=menu>
<li><a href="#L384">Section 1</a>
<li><a href="#details">Section 2</a>
<li><a href="#FAQ">Section 3</a>
</ul>

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 8em;
  margin-top: -2.5em;
}
```

Comment: Provide code in case the link goes dead

Comment: Thanks for the code hint. I'll keep this in mind for future posts.